# Javascript API FETCH With CLICK Event Listener: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, fetch-api

I want to click a button to display API data using JavaScript Fetch but I'm getting trouble with **TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**

I think it has to do with the HTML form. If someone can help me with this. I'm trying to fetch data from NASA APIs.

The JS Code is below

```
var search = document.getElementById("search");
 search.addEventListener("click",function(){
 //var startdate = document.getElementById("starter");
 //var enddate = document.getElementById("enddate");
 var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=key"; 
  fetch(url,{
      method:"GET",
      headers:{
          "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      mode:"cors",
      catch:"default"
  }).then(function(response){
       if(response.ok){
           return response.json();
       }else{
           throw new Error(Error);
       }
   }).then(function(data){
       console.log(data);
   }).catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
   });
 });
```

Below is the HTML form

```
<form>
 <input type="date" id="startdate" placeholder="enter a start date"><br>
<input type="date" id="enddate" placeholder="enter a start date"><br>
<button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try with their api key? the url that you posted is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I have added `event.preventDefault()` this will prevent the page from refreshing. Also do not forget to use the proper API key provided by the service provider.

```js
 var search = document.getElementById("search");
 search.addEventListener("click",function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 //var startdate = document.getElementById("starter");
 //var enddate = document.getElementById("enddate");
 var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=key"; 
  fetch(url,{
      method:"GET",
      headers:{
          "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      mode:"cors",
      catch:"default"
  }).then(function(response){
       if(response.ok){
           return response.json();
       }else{
           throw new Error(Error);
       }
   }).then(function(data){
       console.log(data);
   }).catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
   });
 });
```

Comment: The code is not running, I get a **script error**. Fetch should work with `await` here instead of `then()`. You need `async` in the second arg of the listener before the anonymous function.

Comment: This [url](https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY) with `demo_key` is working: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY

Answer (score 0):

You don't need options for your fetch request,
Also you need to prevent the page from reload

Here is a full working example

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
search.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=key_obtained_from_nasa")
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error();
    }).then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.log('Error! Please try again');
    });
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" id="startdate" placeholder="enter a start date"><br>
  <input type="date" id="enddate" placeholder="enter a start date"><br>
  <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It's working now.. I intentionally did not show the api key